# Encoding multiple live channels

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, udp, multicast, hls

I have a code working that encodes a UDP live channel into an HLS stream using m3u8 container.  My question is, is there a way to simplify doing multiple channels, and ensure each is the same quality as the first?

`c:\tmp\ffmpeg -i udp://239.255.0.109:1234 -acodec aac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -f hls -hls_list_size 10 -hls_time 10 -hls_flags delete_segments /tmp/stream/espn2_hls.m3u8`

The above works - can I just do the following and change the IP and m3u8 stream name?  I feel like this should work, but not completely sure if syntax is 100%, if it can be simplified somewhere, or if I need to up my processing power on the workstation?

```
-i udp://239.255.0.108:1234 -acodec aac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -f hls -hls_list_size 10 -hls_time 10 -hls_flags delete_segments /tmp/stream/espn_hls.m3u8 \
-i udp://239.255.0.111:1234 -acodec aac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -f hls -hls_list_size 10 -hls_time 10 -hls_flags delete_segments /tmp/stream/nfl_hls.m3u8 \
-i udp://239.255.0.113:1234 -acodec aac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -f hls -hls_list_size 10 -hls_time 10 -hls_flags delete_segments /tmp/stream/wbff_hls.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

Close but not quite.

With multiple inputs in a command, the streams for each output still need to be mapped. Without user mapping, ffmpeg will make its own choices, which will be the same for all outputs.

Add maps for each output.

```
-i udp://239.255.0.108:1234 -map 0:v -map 0:a ... /tmp/stream/espn_hls.m3u8 \
-i udp://239.255.0.111:1234 -map 1:v -map 1:a ... /tmp/stream/nfl_hls.m3u8 \
-i udp://239.255.0.113:1234 -map 2:v -map 2:a ... /tmp/stream/wbff_hls.m3u8
```

Comment: Thanks, Gyan. I tried what you suggested, however it seems to only output espn channel consistently and the espn2 hangs after the first couple segments; any ideas?:

`c:\tmp\ffmpeg -i udp://239.255.0.109:1234 -map 0:v -map 0:a -acodec aac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -f hls -hls_list_size 10 -hls_time 10 -hls_flags delete_segments /tmp/stream/espn2_hls.m3u8 -i udp://239.255.0.108:1234 -map 1:v -map 1:a -acodec aac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -f hls -hls_list_size 10 -hls_time 10 -hls_flags delete_segments /tmp/stream/espn_hls.m3u8 `

Comment: Also, anytime i end a line with \ to go to the next (to keep it clean) it seems to mess the whole code up... i thought that was standard syntax?